# How To Set Up An AWS CodeDeploy & EC2 CodeDeploy Secure Environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, aws-code-deploy

While setting up the EC2 and AWS roles for deploying a website from CodeCommit using CodePipeline, there was little detail about the potential security concerns to take into account (following the various online tutorials, which were few and far between)

For the IAM roles for the EC2 Instance, and the AWS CodeDeploy, what is the bare minimum requirements for a secure and safe environment, to be able to deploy.

My environment is using this for development(inside a public subnet), and a live website(inside a private subnet, accessing via ELB).  PHP coded sites.

My concern is somehow someone can inject their own PHP code through some unknown methods and take down the CodeCommit(source) or do other mischievous things.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To use CodeDeploy, IAM role for your EC2 instances should at least have a permission to pull your application artifact from the S3 bucket, and any other permission to AWS services that your website depends on.